# what triggers scons to build files when I have a custom builder?

Tags: scons

I'm going nuts trying to control when files are built in scons. I have a very simple example build tree (see below), with a `Poem` builder that just takes a `.txt` file and converts it to lower case in a corresponding `.eectxt` file.

In my SConstruct and SConscript files, I declare dependencies of 3 .txt files.

But I can't figure out what's putting these into the default build!

```
sconstest/
    SConstruct
    tiger.txt
    src/
        SConscript
        hope.txt
        jabberwocky.txt
```

where the *.txt files are poems and my SConstruct and SConscript look like this:

SConstruct:

```
env = Environment();

def eecummings(target, source, env):
  if (len(target) == 1 and len(source) == 1):
    with open(str(source[0]), 'r') as fin:
        with open(str(target[0]), 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line.lower());
  return None

env['BUILDERS']['Poem'] = Builder(action=eecummings, suffix='.eectxt', src_suffix='.txt');

Export('env');
poems = SConscript('src/SConscript');
tigerPoem = env.Poem('tiger.txt');
```

src/SConscript:

```
Import('env');

input = ['jabberwocky.txt', 'hope.txt'];
output = [env.Poem(x) for x in input];
Return('output');
```

What I want to do is to declare the dependency of the `.eectxt` files from the corresponding `.txt` files, but **not** cause them to be built unless I explicitly put them into the `Default()` build in the SConstruct file, or I request them explicitly at the command line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a directory depends on all files and/or targets which reside in it.
So running:

```
scons
```

Will then build all targets under the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I want, but I still don't understand why I need to do it this way. Acceptance to the first decent answer that explains it.

Here's what works, if I add the following to the root SConstruct file:

```
env.Ignore('.', tigerPoem);
env.Ignore('src', poems);
env.Alias('poems', [tigerPoem]+poems);
```

This ignores the 3 poems from the default target, and then adds them as targets aliased to "poems", so if I run `scons` it builds nothing, but if I run `scons poems` it builds the files.

Why does this work? Why does calling `env.Poem(...)` add something to the default targets?